# Convert Spring xml list with ternary reference to Java config

Tags: spring

I want to convert this Spring bean list to Java config.  But I guess I am confused about how to do the references as a ternary or conditional.

```
<bean id="footerauroraDesktop" class="com.demolight.crawler.elements.PageComponent"
      lazy-init="true">
    <property name="name" value="navigation"/>
    <property name="elements">
        <list>
            <ref bean="continueSessionFromHome"/>
            <ref bean="#{ flag ? 'contactUs' : 'corporateContact' }"/>
            <ref bean="#{ flag ? 'privacyPolicy' : 'returnPolicy' }"/>
            <ref bean="#{ flag ? 'getHelp' : 'aboutUs' }"/>
            <ref bean="#{ flag ? 'siteMap' : 'aboutUs' }"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Why don't you just create the list programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public PageComponent footerauroraDesktop(){
        PageComponent page = new PageComponent();
        page.setName("navigation");
        boolean flag = false; //you should init this here
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(5);
        list.add("continueSessionFromHome");
        if(flag){
            list.add("contactUs");
            list.add("privacyPolicy");
            list.add("getHelp");
            list.add("siteMap");
        } else {
            list.add("corporateContact");
            list.add("returnPolicy");
            list.add("aboutUs");
            list.add("aboutUs");
        }
        page.setElements(list);
        return page;
    }
}
```